# Identify Anonymous orders in BOM list & update accordingly, execute time is taking very long

Tags: vba, excel

Right here, I'm trying to identify whether or not the demand order in  my multi-level BOM list is made by an anonymous customer and then update accordingly.

-In laymens term, I'm checking if an item in the "BOM list sheet"  is an anonymous order. If it is, match the item to the same item in "other sheet" & check whether there is an allocated supply. If no supply allocated, update the "other sheet" accordingly as anonymous, else do nothing. But I'm using arrays instead of worksheets.

1. aRow & bRow refers to current row.
2. value means current column.
3. = vbNullString means no supply allocated

```
  For aRow = 2 To UBound(mArray, 1)
   For bRow = LBound(dArray, 1) + 1 To UBound(dArray, 1) - 1
   

   If dArray(bRow, 15) = "issue SFC-anonymous" Or dArray(bRow, 15) = "issue PRP-anonymous" Then
    If mArray(aRow, 1) = dArray(bRow, 1) And mArray(aRow, 12) = vbNullString Then
       mArray(aRow, 12) = "Anonymous"
    End If
   ElseIf dArray(bRow, 15) = "add INV-PUR" Or dArray(bRow, 15) = "add INV-SFC" Then
       If mArray(aRow, 1) = dArray(bRow, 1) And mArray(aRow, 12) = vbNullString Then
          mArray(aRow, 12) = "Anonymous"
       End If
   End If

    Next bRow
    Next aRow
```

This code is working, but the time it takes to execute is taking about 4-5 minutes which is very long, I assume one reason for this might be because I'm working with string values.

Any advice/criticism to help me improve the code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The code cycles thru the remainder of `dArray` even after meeting the logic condition for setting an `mArray` element to 'Anonymous'.  This is inefficient since replacing the `vbNullString` once is sufficient.  Adding an `Exit For` statement after replacing the `vbNullString` value with 'Anonymous' will remove the inefficiency.
2. Regardless of the string comparisons, the condition for replacing the `mArray` value depends directly on the condition that `mArray(aRow,12) = vbNullString`.  This is known prior to entering the `dArray` loop.  Check for this condition and skip iterating thru the nested loop altogether if the condition is not met.
3. Regardless of the string comparisons, the condition for replacing the `mArray` value depends directly on `mArray(aRow, 1) = dArray(bRow, 1)`.  This is known the immediately after entering the `dArray` loop.  If the condition is not met, skip any other checks in the iteration.

Also, it looks like there is no reason to have an `If` and `ElseIf` based on the code fragment provided.

Below is the code with the changes described above.  Declarations have been added to make the fragment compile.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim aRow As Long
    Dim bRow As Long
    
    Dim dArray As Variant
    Dim mArray As Variant
    
    Dim toCheckFor As String
    
    For aRow = 2 To UBound(mArray, 1)
        If Not mArray(aRow, 12) = vbNullString Then
            For bRow = LBound(dArray, 1) + 1 To UBound(dArray, 1) - 1
                If mArray(aRow, 1) = dArray(bRow, 1) Then
                    toCheckFor = dArray(bRow, 15)
                    If toCheckFor = "issue SFC-anonymous" _
                        Or toCheckFor = "issue PRP-anonymous" _
                        Or toCheckFor = "add INV-PUR" _
                        Or toCheckFor = "add INV-SFC" Then
                        
                            mArray(aRow, 12) = "Anonymous"
                            Exit For
                    End If
                End If
    
            Next bRow
        End If
    Next aRow

End Sub
```

The changes above should improve performance.  However, the code contains both nested loops and `If` statements.  This makes the code very hard to read/understand and maintain.  The code below eliminates the nested loop, improves readability, and will likely have an unnoticeable impact on performance.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim aRow As Long
    
    Dim dArray As Variant
    Dim mArray As Variant
    
    For aRow = 2 To UBound(mArray, 1)
        If Not mArray(aRow, 12) = vbNullString Then
            If MeetsConditionsToSetMArrayValue(dArray, mArray, aRow) Then
                mArray(aRow, 12) = "Anonymous"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next aRow

End Sub

Private Function MeetsConditionsToSetMArrayValue(ByRef dArray As Variant, _
    ByRef mArray As Variant, ByVal aRow As Long) As Boolean
    
    Dim bRow As Long
    For bRow = LBound(dArray, 1) + 1 To UBound(dArray, 1) - 1
        If mArray(aRow, 1) = dArray(bRow, 1) Then
            If ValueMeetsReplacementCriteria(dArray(bRow, 15)) Then
                MeetsConditionsToSetMArrayValue = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        
    Next bRow
    
    MeetsConditionsToSetMArrayValue = False
End Function

Private Function ValueMeetsReplacementCriteria(ByVal valueToCheck As String) As Boolean

    ValueMeetsReplacementCriteria = _
        valueToCheck = "issue SFC-anonymous" _
        Or valueToCheck = "issue PRP-anonymous" _
        Or valueToCheck = "add INV-PUR" _
        Or valueToCheck = "add INV-SFC"

End Function
```

Comment: Hi BZngr, thanks for the help! I was able to utilize this code in my program, I just had to change some parts to make it compatible with my code. Other then that, this code works wonders, saw a significant decrease in run time. Went from a 4-5mintute run to about 30-40seconds for my 20k lines of records. Thanks a bunch!